# Dismiss Keyboard in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

Anyone has a Solution for my Problem?
I have an UITextField and want to Dismiss the Keyboard after pressing on Return.
I added the UITextFieldDelegate and want to set the Delegate on my TextField, but the error remains...

[image: Here is a Screenshot of my Problem]

Comment: Your `chatTextField` is of what type? `UITextField` or `UITextView`?

Comment: Are you sure that, your chatTextField is kind of `UITextField`?

Answer (score 4):

Which one you want to use. TextField or TextView ?

because you create the "IBOutlet" of "TextView" but set the delegate to "TextField".

if you want to use "TextField" then remove "TextView" from storyboard and use "TextField" instead of it and create it's "IBOutlet".

and if you want to use "TextView" then use the "UITextViewDelegate" instead of "UITextFieldDelagate".

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes a short break while coding is necessary :D

Answer (score 3):

Extend `UITextViewDelegate` instead of `UITextFieldDelegate` as your variable `chatTextField` is of type `UITextView`.

Comment: seems like the solution, what does OP has to say about it

Answer (score 2):

Your `chatTextField` is `UITextView` and you are setting it `UITextField's` delegate. ADD `UITextViewDelegate` after class declaration.